# Why am I getting a "no default value" error on a separate column when using "INSERT INTO" on a different column in MySQL Database?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to INSERT INTO one column in MySQL database. When trying to do this, I get an error for "No default value" on an entirely different column in the DB. Why would this be if I'm not trying to insert anything into the column I'm getting the error for?

Query being used with JdbcTemplate from Spring Framework:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO database_1(col1) VALUES(?)";
jdbc.batchUpdate(sql, params);
```

*params is also populated with legitimate parameters*

Output from console: `INSERT INTO database_1(col_1) VALUES(?)]; Field 'col_2' doesn't have a default value; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException`

Comment: Show the `INSERT` query and output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` .. As for now your question is to incomplete to be answerd..

Comment: `NOT NULL` is your problem here -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7gL5jmDjvDq9mS9nPpcaY9/0

Comment: Because INSERT inserts a whole row — that means a new entry in *every* column, not just the ones you mention in your INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Some columns in a table may require a value, that is, `null` values are not allowed. If so, a default value can be specified for the column when the table is created. If you insert a new row in the table without specifying a value for that column, the default value will be used. If no such value was specified when the tables was created you will get the error you got. You either need to specifiy a default value for the column when creating the table, **or** provide one when inserting a new row.